# How to get python version in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Objective: to get python version in shell script

**Observation**:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

**Code**:

```
export python_version=`python --version`
echo "\$python_version=$python_version"
```

**Expected**:

```
$python_version=Python 2.7.5
```

**Actual**:

```
$python_version=
```

Please help me getting python version in shell script.

Comment: Also note, some Linux distributions use different binary names for `python` and, e.g. `python2`. If you have a need for one or the other, it's worth checking how your distribution handles the naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the --version writes to stderr, so:

```sh
export python_version=$(python --version 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The command output being in stderr rather than stdout really tripped me up for a while; definitely wasn't expected behavior for me.

Anyways, if anyone comes here trying to do this on Windows, you can do this:

```
for /f "USEBACKQ tokens=2" %G in (`"python --version 2>&1"`) do set pyVersion=%G
```

You'll then have a string like '2.7.18' in the pyVersion variable.
Remember to expand %G to %%G if using it within a batch script.